# Ansible user ssh sudo PermitRootLogin disabled

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, ansible

i got this working without a problem when the remote serveur doesn't have the ssh parameter :

`PermitRootLogin yes`

My working ansible command:

```
[ansible@myansible ~]$ ansible remoteserveur -a "cat /etc/sudoers"
```

I want to change the ssh parameter on all my servers to `PermitRootLogin no` for the security. When this is done, it's no more working.

```
UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
```

How could i keep my ansible's user being a **normal user** and having the possibility via **ansible to run command as root**.

Many thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you do not have "become: yes" directive in your Ansible playbook? This directive is responsible for privileged access for the Ansible agent.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Nikolay, it gave me the good way to resolve the problem.
I finaly use :

```
ansible-playbook permitrootlogin.yml -b -K
```

-b for "become" and -K "ask for privilege escalation password"

```
TASK [Disallow root SSH access] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1]
ok: [server2]
```